# ThreeJS: PlaneBufferGeometry, raycasting and faces

Tags: three.js

Made a buffered plane, set its vertices with:

```
var vertices = tg.attributes.position.array;
geometry.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
```

Now i want to raycast to a face to get it's Z value:

```
var z = intersects[i].object.geometry.vertices[intersects[i].face.a].z;
```

This worked on a standard geometry as it had faces and lot of other things i'm trying to save from memory.

My question comes from the index: intersects[i].face.a. What do i have to add? There seem not to be a method to add "faces" to the buffered geometry. Right now there is just one face for the whole geometry at:

```
object.face.(a,b,c)
```

Perhaps there is another way of clicking on a face and getting it's vertex value when using buffered geoms.

Tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer geometries contain attributes of positions in an array.

If you want to obtain information about z-value of a specific vertex from a buffer geometry's vertices then you can do it like this:

```
intersects[i].object.geometry.attributes.position.array[intersects[i].face.a * 3 + 2]
```

also you can use the z-coordinate of the point of intersection (which is in world's coordinates):

```
intersects[i].point.z;
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/d1jr3yd3/) example (see `function showDetails(intersect)`, the green plane is `THREE.PlaneGeometry`, the blue plane is `THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry`)

Comment: Thanks. But in my mesh, the face is always the same. It does not change values. That's why i'm thinking i'd add faces. Please note i'm not using generatefromgeometry, i started from scratch,

Comment: Perhaps my raycasting is flawled? Will check it after holidays 

Comment: You can make jsfiddle. It would be better way to help you. Happy holidays ;)

Comment: Yep, the raycaster was broke. Also had to do a *3 + 1 instead of 2, but it worked! Thanks a lot and happy new year!